# How to output a default result when my query returns nothing after entering filters in the where clause?

Tags: sql, null, where-clause

I have several complex queries, and have to be generic about content, but the gist is that we have a system for using queries to generate tabular dashboards. Part of this system lets us insert filters like dates or values into the Where clause. When filtering the query may or may not contain results based on those filters.

Here is a really generalized example. The filter is denoted by [[]].

mytable:

| recordid | column_a | column_b | column_c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | one | two | three |
| 1002 | one | three | two |
| 1003 | two | three | one |
| 1004 | two | one | three |

and my query is:

```sql
select recordid is ID, column_a as A, column_b as B, column_c as C

from mytable

where [[column_a = (value picked from list)]] and [[column_b = (value picked from list)]]
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to output something when the selected filters result in an empty set? I know how to use different functions to check if the column values are null/empty, but that isn't getting me the results I need. I don't know if there's a way to check the output of a query, see no results, then output a row of values like "null" or "n/a" or something for my clients to see on their UI.

For example if someone did the following:

```sql
select recordid as ID, column_a as A, column_b as B, column_c as C

from mytable

where [[column_a = one]] and [[column_b = one]]
```

This would result in an empty result. I would like if it could output something like:

| recordid | column_a | column_b | column_c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| n/a | n/a | n/a | n/a |

I'm not even sure if this is possible. Any thoughts/advice is welcome.

Comment: This sounds like something the UI should be handling by default. Any SQL solution will require you to tag your specific RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

This is more a logical scenario. Their are multiple ways to do this.
Following is a concept that can be used.

```
---Get count of query and if it is 0 then display 'na'
DECLARE @count as int=(
select count(1) from (
select * from table3
where column_a = 'one' and column_b = 'two' ) temp);

if @count=0
select top 1 'na' as recordid , 'na' as column_a, 'na' as column_b, 'na' as column_c  from table3

if @count<>0
select * from table3
where column_a = 'one' and column_b = 'two'
```

There should be other more efficient ways but you might got the concept.